# Html.TextBoxFor regex is not working

Tags: javascript, html, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two helpers: `Html.TextBox` and `Html.TextBoxFor`

```
Html.TextBox(someId, someValue, new { @class = "text-box single-line numericPropertyValue",  regexp=@"^(-?\d{0,9}([.]\d{0,5})?)?$", minValue = someMinValue, maxValue = someMaxValue, invalidValueMessage = ValidationMessages.ValueIsIncorrect(), invalidRangeMessage = ValidationMessages.InvalidRangeMessage(someMinValue, someMaxValue) })
```

This one specifies Budget and allows me to input only `digits.digits` and works fine.

Another one is `Html.TextBoxFor`:

```
 Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.some.Name, new { @class = "text-box single-line numericPropertyValue", regExp = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]", invalidValueMessage = "value is invalid" })
```

This one specifies Name for some item, never mind. But my regex is not working. However, if I put there regex from the first `Html.TextBox`, it is still not working and allows me to enter everything.

Do u know what is wrong with my `TextBoxFor`?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because passing `regExp` doesn't do anything. The members of that anonymous object end up as HTML attributes on your input, and `regExp` is not a valid HTML attribute. Use `pattern` instead if you're looking to use client-side validation provided by the browser. However, note that `pattern` is only supported in modern browsers (IE10+). So you'll need a fallback for less capable browsers.

Comment: Ok, but this allert I get from HTML5. Do u have any ideas how to cover this problem in another way?